# Why I get error 'no instance of type' on map method?

Tags: java, modelmapper

I have this function:

```
public <D> List<D> mapList(Object source, List<D> targetClass) {
    return targetClass
            .stream()
            .map(element -> modelMapper.map(source, element))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

On this row:

```
    map(element -> modelMapper.map(source, element))
```

I have this error:

```
no instance of type variable r exists so that void conforms to r
```

Any idea why I get the error above and how to fix it?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` method on `Stream` class return a `Stream`.

```
<R> Stream<R> map(Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper);
```

`ModelMapper` `map` method returns `void`.

```
public void map(Object source, Object destination) {
```

Therefore the error. "void" cannot be streamed.

Comment: Any idea if it can be solved with streams, or should I use an old attitude and work with for loops?

Comment: After modelmapper.map,  return element. {modelMapper.map(source, element); return element;}

Answer (score 1):

Types do not match the as compiler error suggests, the returned type is void and will not be collected . I guess the map method on modelMapper is overloaded and you can pass the class type on second argument as well to resolve the issue.
some thing like

```
Foo foo = modelMapper.map(map, Foo.class);
```